# How to prevent ampersand from duplicating in Export to Word RTF in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2010, rtf, ampersand

We have an Access database that has a feature to print a notification letter from a report.  Sometimes, we have to use an address different from the database, in which case we use the Export - Word RTF File command to edit the address in MS Word and print from there.

Here's the problem.  The name of our department, "Compensation & Pension" or the abbreviation "C&P" appears just fine...until we export it to Word RTF.  The output comes out as "Compensation && Pension" or "C&&P."  Is there an easy fix for this in the Access report, other than simply editing out the additional ampersand when we do the export?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I figured out a resolution...sort of.  The person who created the report didn't do a very good job of a lot of things, not just with the ampersand, but with his use of bold and underlining.  It looks fine when the letter is printed directly from the report, but when exported, the RTF document has some things hidden by spillover from other text covering fields such as a date pulled from the database.  Since he is not willing to fix the formatting problems with the report, and I'm not allowed to play with the Access program, I decided to say "the heck with it" (or something along those lines) and just pasted the text into a Word document, reformatted it so it looks good, and saved it as a Word template.  When I need this letter, I just paste in the name and address as shown in Access.  Does that defeat the purpose of the Access program?  Sort of, but since I only this letter two or three times a week, I figured there is no point burning more bridges than I already have with my boss.

Comment: That's not really an answer, a comment would have been more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see "comment."  Since I was the original poster of the question, I thought it would be appropriate to post a follow-up to close the loop.  It would have been nice if someone had answered my question...perhaps you could have done that instead of giving me a -1.